# How do I safely remove Ubuntu 12.04 LTS from a dual-boot with Windows 8?

Tags: 12.04, boot, dual-boot, uninstall, uefi

I installed Ubuntu 12.04 LTS yesterday, and ran into a few problems (Windows not booting..)
However, I think I fixed that by booting windows 8 in 'UEFI recovery' (or something like that) - there is no discernible difference between the Windows I am running now and the Windows I was running before.

However, I would like to uninstall Ubuntu, but I don't want to mess up my computer (again!)
How do I go about doing this *safely*?

I did some research and found these 2 conflicting YouTube videos, explaining 2 different ways of doing it: which way should I use? And if none of those YouTube videos are correct, which way should I use?

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TcE3gkzwQSY

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mTDCwLEU6ng

I am using a Lenovo Z500 laptop, if that's of importance.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: just post what you had tried,rather than posting video links.

Answer (score 0):

I have used the method described in the second YouTube video. The one that I most used is to run recovery disk, install windows clean and reload all the software and data. Understandably this method is time consuming.

PS: If you post more detail on the current state of your computer you might get a better response.